# I'd rlly love to solve unknown problem in my program

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

**Index was outside the bounds of an array** *-compiler told me once I ran my program*

**The problem is at line 44** *-he said*

PLEASE HELP ME GUYS

```
    static string[] timeArr = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty", "tweny one", "twenty two", "twenty three", "twenty four","twenty five", "twent six", "twenty seven", "twenty eight", "twenty nine", "thirty"};

    static string GetMinutesInWords(int minutes){
            string minutesPreposition = "past";
            minutesStr = timeArr[minutes];
            if (minutes>=31){
                minutes-=30;
                minutesPreposition="to";
                minutesStr = timeArr[minutes];
            }
            minutesStr+=minutesPreposition;
            return minutesStr;
        }
```

Comment: You're getting the array at index minutes prior to the if condition, so if you're passing in an int larger than 31, the index is going to be out of bounds.

Answer (score -2):

```
static string GetMinutesInWords(int minutes){
        string minutesPreposition = "past";
        
        if (minutes>=31){
            minutes-=30;
            minutesPreposition="to";


            minutesStr = timeArr[minutes];
        }
        minutesStr+=minutesPreposition;
        return minutesStr;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a description explaining what change you did and why.